# Buffered Writer - Writing strings with "\n" inside

Tags: java, bufferedwriter

I was wondering if it's possible to send a **single** string with newline characters using BufferedWriter.

For context I need to send the following string over the network:

```
String message = "LOOKREPLY\nX...X\n.....\n.....\n.....\nX...X"
socketOutput = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
socketOutput.write(message + "\n");
```

But this sends 6 messages over the network because of the newline characters. I could re-build it on the client side but was wondering if there's a neater/simpler approach.

Comment: Are you by chance reading it from the other end with `BufferedReader.readline()`? That method explicitly reads until a newline (which it discards.) So it's not that you're sending 6 messages, it's that you are reading the one message as 6 lines. If you want to preserve the newlines, you need to either use the `read()` method, or else you need to escape them prior to sending and unescape them after receiving them.

Comment: @dlev yes you r right that's why he stated "6 messages".

Comment: If the message delimiter is \n you're sending 6 messages. You have to make up your mind what it is you're trying to do. Possibly you need an escape convention for new lines inside messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code

```
bw.write(message+"\n");
```

As it will put `\n` after all message has been written.

`BufferedWriter` will *not send 6 Messages* it will send only one but as you gave `\n` in your string it will write according to that.

As delv said you can put escape sequence to the `\n` so that it will write only one line.

```
String message = "LOOKREPLY\\nX...X\\n.....\\n.....\\n.....\\nX...X";
```

So that message will be written like this.

```
LOOKREPLY\nX...X\n.....\n.....\n.....\nX...X
```

Comment: Good.No Problem.GladToHelpYou. :)